# How lambda function executes background timers?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

When setTimeout is wrapped in Promise that code executed in aws lamda but normal setTimeout function not executed. How Nodejs event loop is handled inside aws lamda execution environment?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
           // This part not executed
    }, 1*1000);

    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(function() {
            // This part executed
            resolve('works');
        }, 3*1000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Timer starts fine, but the execution of the Lambda finish before it resolves - everything not packed in the returned Promise is ignored.

In the second case a Promise is returned and because the whole handler function is declared as `async`, which packs its result always into a Promise, the returned Promise result is flatted and returned correctly.